# Poisson point process in 2D with reflecting boundaries

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Consider a point process $\{(X_n,T_n)\}$ on a plane $[0,1/\lambda]\times\mathbf R^+$, generated from a Poisson point process $\{T_n\}$ with rate $\lambda$ on $\mathbf R^+$ (i.e. $(T_n-T_{n-1})$ is iid exponentially distributed $\sim\lambda\exp(-\lambda T)$) in the following way:

$X_0=T_0=0$ and the boundaries at $0$ and $1/\lambda$ are reflecting. The $X_n$ step direction is unchanged until hitting the boundary (or one can consider unbiased random walk alternatively), The step size is given by

1. $X_n = T_n-T_{n-1}$ , or
2. $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,T_n-T_{n-1}]$ , or
3. $X_n$ is exponentially distributed with mean $T_n-T_{n-1}$

Q: Is this 2D point process Poissonian in each of the three cases? If so, is it homogeneous?

Comment: I think i can answer your question. Can you elaborate what you mean by reflecting preciesly?  and you mean $T_n-T_{n-1}\sim exp(\lambda)$ instead of what you wrote right?

Comment: @Conformal By reflecting I mean intuitively if the random process generates a $X_n$ that goes outside the interval $[0,1/\lambda]$, say $X'_n<0$, connect $X'_n, X_{n-1}$ with a straight line and take a reflection at the left boundary $X=0$, then if the reflected $X'_n$ ends up inside the interval, then take that point to be $X_n$; if $X'_n>1/\lambda$, then repeat the process until we obtain a legit $X_n$. I mean the inter-arrival time between two points are drawn from an exponential distribution, which is of the form I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases i denote the 2d random measure by $\pi$.

1)  no its not, we don't have increment independence. Take two events $A=(\pi([0,1/\lambda) \times [\frac{2}{4\lambda},\frac{3}{4\lambda}) = 1), B=(\pi([\frac{3}{4\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda})\times [\frac{3}{4\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda} = 1)$. Clearly $P(A),P(B)>0$. Since the two boxes are disjoint, we should have
$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)>0$. But under the event $A$, the T process has a jump at $[\frac{2}{4\lambda},\frac{3}{4\lambda})$, so if $T$ had another jump in $ [\frac{3}{4\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda})$, the increment of $T$ would be smaller than $\frac{1}{2\lambda}$, and thus its corresponding $X$ would be bounded by $\frac{1}{2\lambda}$. Therefore $P(A\cap B)=0$

2)  no its not, for the exact same reason as in 1). Take two events $A=(\pi([0,1/\lambda) \times [\frac{2}{4\lambda},\frac{3}{4\lambda}) = 1), B=(\pi([\frac{3}{4\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda})\times [\frac{3}{4\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda} = 1)$. Clearly $P(A),P(B)>0$. Since the two boxes are disjoint, we should have
$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)>0$. But under the event $A$, the T process has a jump at $[\frac{2}{4\lambda},\frac{3}{4\lambda})$, so if $T$ had another jump in $ [\frac{3}{4\lambda},\frac{1}{\lambda})$, the increment of $T$ would be smaller than $\frac{1}{2\lambda}$, and thus its corresponding $X$ would be bounded by $\frac{1}{2\lambda}$. Therefore $P(A\cap B)=0$

3) No its not. analogous to point 2). I will leave exact calculations to you, but with same events A,B as in 2) you see that $P(B)$ will be smaller given $A$, because the $X$ drawn in event $B$ is drawn from an exponential distribution with small mean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in case 1, the mean measure density vanishes apart from this reflected line,right? I wonder if I make each jump in case 1 a random walk, i.e. each step can go left(negative) or right(positive). I suppose it is still 2d poissonian but how will the mean measure density look like?

Comment: Apologies. My old answer to 1) was "yes, its the 2d poisson process with mean measure being the 1 dim. Lebesque measure transformed to the line (x,x),x∈R+ starting at 0 and then reflected at the boundaries [0,1/λ]. Clearly this process can only hit that reflected line by construction. In particular its not homogeneous. However, it bears a close resemblance to the 1d homogeneous process."

But this is for the process where $X_n=T_n$, which is not what you asked in $1)$. I edited my answer to the correct assumption namely $X_n=T_n-T_{n-1}$. The 1) case is completely analogous to the 2) case.

Comment: my bad. actually by step size I do mean $X_n-X_{n-1}$ rather than $X_n$ in cases 1,2,3. So I guess your original answer to case 1 is okay. What about your conclusions to 2,3? see my edits to the questions

Comment: I don't think its recommendable to change the question substantially after it has been answered. Instead i suggest you change it back and pose a new question.

Comment: make sense. I changed it back. Nevertheless, you have any opinions on if it's the other case?

Comment: I just made some quick drawings on a sheet of paper and it seems clear that neither of 2) or 3) in your modified case are Poisson processes. Both fail increment independence.

Comment: Last question, which I asked in my first comment, what if I consider unbiased random walk at each step with the step size $X_{n}-X_{n-1}=T_{n}-T_{n-1}$? I suppose it is still 2d poissonian but how will the mean measure density look like?

Comment: no not poisson either, there are simply too many points. The induced random walk will be neighbourhood recurrent, so all open intervals on the reflected line (mentioned in my 2nd comment), would contain infinitely many points.

Comment: I don't quite get it. If there is no random walk, then it is 2d poissonian with the mean measure concentrated on the reflected line. Intuitively, why adding a random left/right choice makes the reflected line contain infinitely many points?

Comment: I may missunderstand you. Im talking about the case where the entire touple $(T_n,X_n)$ changing with increment $U*(T_n-T_{n-1},T_n-T_{n-1})$, where $U$ is a fair coin choosing between$1 $ and $-1$. You may be asking about the case where the increment is $(U*(T_n-T_{n-1}),T_n-T_{n-1})$. Then again we do not have increment independence. Intuitively, if you know there is a jump at some $(0,t)$ then you know that there can not be a jump at $(1/\lambda,t)$ because your process $(X_n,T_n)$ can't move horizontally.